# Issue with invalid syntax error in python 2.7.3

Tags: python, fasta

I am trying to run a script (see below) to read in a fasta file and output a taxonomy file (printing only the sequence header without the '>' character) but I keep getting a syntax error which I have not been able to resolve. As a result the script creates the cleanseqs.tax file but the file is blank. Could anyone help?

Thank you!

```
>>> Fasta = open("testseqs.fasta", "r")
>>> Tax = open("cleanseqs.tax", "w")
>>> while 1:
...     SequenceHeader= Fasta.readline()
...     Sequence= Fasta.readline()
...     if SequenceHeader == '':
...             break
...     Tax.write(SequenceHeader.replace('>', ''))
... Fasta.close()
  File "<stdin>", line 7
    Fasta.close()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> Tax.close()
```

Comment: Obligatory comment: there are tried and tested FASTA parsers out there that you can use. I can post an example if you think it's relevant

Comment: Do some of these allow the removal of the > character as well? Yes that would be great if you could. Thank you

Comment: I posted a couple of examples in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [file object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close) is a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types), so you can use the [with statement](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to automatically close the files:

```
with open("testseqs.fasta", "r") as fasta, open("cleanseqs.tax", "w") as tax:
    while True:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in an extra line, as `... Fasta.close()` isn't necessarily the end of the while loop. It could take in another keyword, like `else`. Adding another line implies the end of the while loop.

Or did you mean to indent `Fasta.close()`?

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter thinks you are trying to put the `Fasta.close()` call inside the `while`-loop, but the line is improperly indented. Just press enter when you want to end the `while` block.

Also it would be ideal here to use the `with`-statement so you can get rid of the `close()`-calls entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As you requested, here are a couple of examples with existing FASTA parsers:

Example file:

```
$ cat test.fasta 
>header1 description1
SEQUENCE
>header2 description2
SEQUENCESEQUENCE
```

1. With [`BioPython.SeqIO`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO):

   ```
   from Bio import SeqIO
   reader = SeqIO.parse('test.fasta', 'fasta')
   with open('biopython.tax', 'w') as out:
       for prot in reader:
           out.write(prot.description + '\n')
   reader.close()
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   $ cat biopython.tax 
   header1 description1
   header2 description2
   ```
2. With [`pyteomics.fasta`](https://pyteomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#fasta) (`pyteomics` is a library developed by me and my colleagues):

   ```
   from pyteomics import fasta
   with open('pyteomics.tax', 'w') as out, fasta.read('test.fasta') as reader:
       for prot in reader:
           out.write(prot.description + '\n')
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   $ cat pyteomics.tax 
   header1 description1
   header2 description2
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my program would write in a file but file turned out to be empty.

Correct your indent and then close the file, content will be present in file after closing it in python.